# Loopback 4 - Not able to get metadata from array of classes injected with @inject.tag()

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, loopback4

Have a couple of classes registered as services:

```ts
@processor('some_value')
export class MyService {}

@processor('another_value')
export class AnotherService {}
```

This services are decorated with the processor() decorator, defined like this:

```ts
const PROCESSOR_CLASS_META = MetadataAccessor.create<
    string,
    ClassDecorator
  >('processor-decorator-metadata');

export function processor(value): ClassDecorator {
  return (
    target: Function & {value?: string},
  ) => {
    bind({tags: 'processor'})(target);

    const decorator = ClassDecoratorFactory.createDecorator(
      PROCESSOR_CLASS_META,
      value,
      {decoratorName: '@processor'},
    );
    decorator(target);
  };
}
```

The decorator do two things - tags the class as 'processor' and sets a `string` type metadata.

Now I have a third service. In this service I inject all the services tagged 'processor' like this:

```ts
export class consumerService {
  constructor(
    @inject.tag('processor')
    private readonly processorClasses: Constructor<Function>,
  )
}
```

When I try to get the metadata of the injected classes I get `undefined`:

```ts
export class consumerService {
  constructor(
    @inject.tag('processor')
    private readonly processorClasses: Constructor<Function>,
  )
  
  public getMetaData() {
    return this.processorClasses.map((processorClass) => {
      // Returns undefined
      return MetadataInspector.getClassMetadata(
        PROCESSOR_CLASS_META,
        processorClass,
      );
    })
  }
}
```

The `undefined` comes only when I inject an array of bindings with @inject.tag() decorator.
When I inject only one of the classes I get the expected result:

```ts
export class consumerService {
  constructor(
    @inject('services.MyService')
    private readonly myService: MyService,
  )
  
  // Returns 'some_value' as expected.
  public getMetaData() {
      return MetadataInspector.getClassMetadata(
        PROCESSOR_CLASS_META,
        this.myService,
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator `@inject.tag()` is injecting service *instances*, not *classes*. You can access the class (constructor function) via `.constructor` property.

Here is a fixed version of your `ConsumerService` implementation:

```
class ConsumerService {
  constructor(
    @inject.tag('processor')
    private readonly processors: object[],
  ) {
    console.log('processors', this.processors);
    for (const proc of this.processors) {
      console.log(
        it.constructor.name,
        MetadataInspector.getClassMetadata(
          PROCESSOR_CLASS_META,
          proc.constructor,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it using your example processors, I get the following output:

```
processors [ MyService {}, AnotherService {} ]
MyService some_value
AnotherService another_value
```